# Display page before Ubercart checkout

Tags: ubercart

We have a Drupal7 shopping website and it uses [ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) for the shopping experience.

Before checkout we want to display a page enticing users to buy additional items, so the requirement is a separate page not a pane etc.

Could anyone let me know how to accomplish the same please.

Thanks

Comment: How about instead of creating a new page you override the ubercart checkout page and write your code there. You may refer this like [here](http://codekarate.com/blog/overriding-ubercart-checkout-page) that explains how to Overriding Ubercart Checkout page